# Accidentally typed password in username input, any logs to clear?

Tags: security, ssh, password

I have accidentally typed my password in SSH's interactive username prompt. Are there any log files that I should clear?

Comment: Clear your ssh logfile if it exists.I mean your auth.log.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/var/log/auth.log`

Search for "Invalid user"

Answer (score 3):

`/var/log/btmp` contains, in binary form, a log of the details of failed login attempts.

`last -f /var/log/btmp` will show you the contents of that file, which will likely include your mistake.

Comment: ``lastb`` is a system defined shortcut for the same.